# "Has" or "have" in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, pronouns

> Mr. Raj is one of the famous teachers who **has/have** come to teach you now.

I'm confused between the two. I think *have* should come. But here noun is singular so *has* could also come.

Comment: A plural noun or noun phrase should follow  “one of the”.  Please edit the question and change  *teacher* to *teachers*.  If that obviates your question, then delete it.

Comment: Are you sure about the **now** being there at the end?

Comment: @hjpotter92: Yes I'm sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subject of the relative clause is *who*. It stands in place of *the famous teachers*. That makes it plural, so you need *have*.